# Compute weighted average by group in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have quarterly data on portfolio holdings, let's call the table `holdings`,

```
portfolio date         security    dollar_amount
p1        03/31/2001   security1   50
p1        03/31/2001   security2   100
p2        03/31/2001   security1   25
p2        03/31/2001   security2   50

p1        06/30/2001   security1   50
p1        06/30/2001   security2   100
p1        06/30/2001   security3   50
p2        06/30/2001   security1   25
p2        06/30/2001   security3   50
```

and data on monthly returns for each security, let's call it `returns`

```
security    date         return
security1   03/31/2001   1
security2   03/31/2001   -1
security3   03/31/2001   2

security1   04/30/2001   3
security2   04/30/2001   -1
security3   04/30/2001   2

security1   05/31/2001   1
security2   05/31/2001   2
security3   05/31/2001   -1

security1   06/30/2001   2
security2   06/30/2001   -1
security3   06/30/2001   3

security1   07/31/2001   2
security2   07/31/2001   -3
security3   07/31/2001   1

security1   08/30/2001   2
security2   08/30/2001   -3
security3   08/30/2001   2
```

For each portfolio, here `p1` and `p2`, I want to compute monthly weighted average returns for each portfolio: `SUM(dollar_amount * return) / SUM(dollar_amount)`. However, I want to take into account that there are quarterly changes in holdings, that is the weights should adjust every quarter.

Desired output:

```
portfolio date        return
p1        03/31/2001  1/3*1 + 2/3*(-1) = -1/2
p2        03/31/2001  1/3*1 + 2/3*(-1) = -1/2
p1        04/30/2001  1/3*3 + 2/3*(-1) = 1/3
p2        04/30/2001  1/3*3 + 2/3*(-1) = 1/3
p3        05/31/2001  1/3*1 + 2/3*2 = 5/3
p4        05/31/2001  1/3*1 + 2/3*2 = 5/3

-- rebalancing, i.e. adjusting the weights according to holding data --

p1        06/30/2001  1/4*2 + 1/2*(-1) + 1/4*3 = 3/4
p2        06/30/2001  1/3*2 + 2/3*3 = 8/3
p1        07/31/2001  1/4*2 + 1/2*(-3) + 1/4*1 = -3/4
p2        07/31/2001  1/3*2 + 2/3*1 = 4/3
p3        08/30/2001  1/4*2 + 1/2*(-3) + 1/4*2 = -1/2
p4        08/30/2001  1/3*2 + 2/3*2 = 2
```

My final query will have to work with 53 quarters of holdings data and thus 159 months. The number of unique portfolios and securities are up to 13,000.

**My question is whether there is a meaningful way to do it in a single SQLite query. If not, what do you think is the best way to do it?**

The problems for me are

- joining only the relevant (monthly) returns data for each quarter, e.g. returns from `03/31/2001`, `04/30/2001`, `05/31/2001` for the portfolio weights from `03/31/2001`; otherwise the data would explode.
- that the weighted average returns have to be computed per group, where a group is defined by quarter and portfolio.

The only way I can think of is to query the weighted average return *per date and portfolio*, such that I would have to loop through all of these combinations. I am aware that this is a computationally costly job, but I am looking for the fastest solution here.

Thanks for your help! I am using Python, sqlalchemy, sqlite3.

Comment: There some issues here, expected output is not based on sample data, what time period do you want to query, the second bullet point at the end is very hard to understand what it is about (at least for me). Furthermore isn't the formula `SUM(dollar_amount * return) / SUM(dollar_amount) => SUM(dollar_amount) * return / SUM(dollar_amount) => return`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: I edited my question to make it more precise. Regarding your question on the formula: Your proposal simplifies to `return`, so this is not what I want. I want a weighted average, i.e. take the sum of products of weight and return and divide it by the sum of weights.

Comment: I understand the formula now with the latest edit.

Comment: Is there no straightforward solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my take at it but Sqlite doesn't have much support for working with dates so it feels a little inefficient. I could not get it to work with your date format so I hade to change to 'yyyy-mm-dd' but maybe that is installation specific

```
SELECT portfolio, r.date, 1.0 * SUM(dollar_amount * return) / SUM(dollar_amount)
FROM returns r
JOIN holdings h ON h.security = r.security AND
    strftime('%Y',h.date) = strftime('%Y',r.date) AND 
    CAST(strftime('%m',r.date) as int) BETWEEN cast(strftime('%m',h.date) as int) AND CAST(strftime('%m',h.date) as int) + 2

GROUP BY portfolio, r.date
ORDER BY r.date
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not know the functionality, that's great. I slightly rewrote your command, it works with one fewer condition. I confirmed that it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/bd586/3